# Cannot replace data with modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When I want to change input using modal, the changed data is the last input...Not the corresponding button I clicked on.

**Here is my code** ():

**dashboard.php**

```
<div id="modalPartID" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:70%;overflow-y: initial !important;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Browse PartID</h4>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchPartID" placeholder="PartID"/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>PartID</th>
          <th>PartName</th>
          <th>OtherID</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="tbodyPartID"></tbody>
        </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**dashboard.js**

```
function addTableRowHasilProduksi() {
  row = parseInt($('#tableRowHasilProduksi').val()) + 1;
  $('#plusButtonHasilProduksi').remove();
  var html = ' \
    <tr id="rowTableHasilProduksi_' + row + '"> \
      <td> \
        <div class="input-group"> \
          <input id="typepartid_' + row + '" class="form-control ui-autocomplete" type="text" onchange="myFunction(' + row + ')" name="typepartid_' + row + '"  >\
          <span class="input-group-btn">\
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" name="button" id="buttonPartID' + row + '">\
          </button>\
          </span>\
        </div>\
      </td> \
      <td>\
        <select id="hasilproduksi_' + row + '" class="form-control" placeholder="select" onchange="hasilProduksiChage(' + row + ')" name="hasilproduksi_' + row + '"> \
        <option value="-">--Select--</option>\
        <option value="Good">Good</option>\
        <option value="Repair">Repair</option>\
        <option value="Reject">Reject</option>\
        </select> \
      </td> \
      <td><input id="qty_' + row + '" type="text" class="form-control"  onkeydown="return numbersonly(this, event);" onkeyup="javascript:tandaPemisahTitik(this);" name="qty_' + row + '" /> \
      </td> \
      <td id="tdTypeReject_' + row + '"> \
        <select id="typereject_' + row + '" class="form-control" name="typereject_' + row + '"> \
        ' + htmlTypeReject + ' \
        </select> \
      </td> \
      <td><input id="keteranganreject_' + row + '" type="text" class="form-control" name="keteranganreject_' + row + '"/></td> \
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="deleteRowHasilProduksi(' + row + ')">x</button></td> \
    </tr> \
    <tr id="plusButtonHasilProduksi"> \
      <td colspan="6"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" style="width:100%" onclick="addTableRowHasilProduksi()">+</button></td> \
    </tr>';
  $('#tableHasilProduksi > tbody').append(html);
  //variable row table add +1
  $('#tableRowHasilProduksi').val(row);
  $('#plusButtonHasilProduksi').attr('onclick', 'addTableRowDowntime()');
  //buttonPartID onBrowse
  $('#buttonPartID' + row + '').click(function() {
    browsePartID(0, 100, '');
  });
  $('#searchPartID'+ row + '').keyup(function(e) {
    var filter = (e.target.value);
    browsePartID(0, 100, filter)
  });
}
```

**browse.js**

```
$('#buttonPartID').click(function() {
  browsePartID(0, 100, '');
});
$('#searchPartID').keyup(function(e) {
  var filter = (e.target.value);
  browsePartID(0, 100, filter)
});
function browsePartID(start, limit, filter) {
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'api/partid.php?start=' + start + '&limit=' + limit + '&filter=' + filter,
    success: function(result) {
      var data = result.result;
      var trData = '';

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        trData += ' \
          <tr> \
          <td><a onclick="isiFormPartID(\'' + data[i].PartID + '\')">' + data[i].PartID + '</a></td> \
          <td><a onclick="isiFormPartID(\'' + data[i].PartID + '\')">' + data[i].PartName + '</a></td> \
          <td><a onclick="isiFormPartID(\'' + data[i].PartID + '\')">' + data[i].OtherID + '</a></td> \
          </tr> \
          ';
      }

      $('#tbodyPartID').html(trData);
      $('#modalPartID').modal('show');
    }
  });
}

function isiFormPartID(PartID) {
  $('input#typepartid_'+row).val(PartID);
  $('#modalPartID').modal('hide');
}
```

**LAST**
Maybe you can give me solution, CMIIW. Sorry my english is bad.

Look at this picture, maybe you will understand what I mean.

[image: illustration]

Comment: Do you mean, the selected `partID` should show in the selected input. Am I Right?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first click is made on the folder icon in a table row... That triggers the ajax request to get the parts in the modal. Then, you wish to copy the infos of that part to the page's table?

Comment: yes the selected partID should show in the selected input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... If I got that right, the issue is about the `row` variable.

Since I cannot test your code, I just can ask you to try what is below.
If it doesn't work, please create a CodePen looking like your project. Just use static HTML in the modal, since you won't be able to make the ajax request.

So, from the folder icon click:

```
$('#buttonPartID' + row + '').click(function() {
  browsePartID(0, 100, '');
});
```

Change it to:

```
$("[id^='buttonPartID']").click(function() {  
  row = $(this).closest("tr").index();        // Keep the row number in variable.
  browsePartID(0, 100, '');
});
```

The use the saved `row` variable in the second click handler:

```
function isiFormPartID(PartID) {
  $('input#typepartid_'+row).val(PartID);     // You were using is correctly here, but the value wasn't correct.
  $('#modalPartID').modal('hide');
}
```

Comment: so, i must change modal in html ( dashboard.php ) ?

Comment: Start with the chages I suggest near «Change it to:».

Comment: i have followed your idea, but the modal doesn't show

Comment: Do you have a live link to your site?

Comment: check my website, user : adminkg , pass : 9999 https://miyakoproduksi.000webhostapp.com/laporanproduksi/index.php

Comment: after login go to https://miyakoproduksi.000webhostapp.com/laporanproduksi/dashboard.php